# CORS preflight channel did not succeed...Although other request are working properly but one request is having this cors error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have an angular app and node backend and all the request is properly working but when I try to use a get request and inside that I am redirecting the request then 'CORS preflight channel did not succeed' this error is happening...when I am trying in postman I am getting my desire result...but not in browser

```
router.get('/monthdata/:month' ,  jwtHelper.verifyJwtToken , ctrlData.getMonthData);
router.post('/monthdata' , jwtHelper.verifyJwtToken , ctrlData.postMonthData);
```

```
module.exports.postMonthData = (req , res , next) =>{
    let month = req.body.month;
    //console.log(`/api/monthdata/${month}` );
    res.redirect(`/api/monthdata/${month}`);
}


module.exports.getMonthData = (req , res , next) =>{
    Data.find({
        _creator : req._id , month : req.params.month
    } , (err , data)=>{
        if(!data)
            return res.status(400).json({status : false , message : 'Data notfound'})
        else
            return res.status(200).json({status: true , data})
    });
}
```

Comment: "when I am trying in postman I am getting my desire result" ...that's because non-ajax requests are not subject to CORS restrictions

Comment: Can you show how you make the request in your browser, and exactly what the full error message says

Comment: Also, have you actually configured CORS support in your node server? I can't see any evidence of it above

Comment: ` 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use('/api' , rtxIndex);`

Comment: **These are the errors --Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/monthdata/0. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/monthdata. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).**

Comment: The IP address 0.0.0.0 here is very odd. Are you sure you're running both the app and the server properly over http:// (not file://)?

Comment: yes, every other request are running fine with the same IP

Comment: What do you mean "same IP"? You can't be running your server with IP 0.0.0.0. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0. Please clarify the situation properly.

Comment: Earlier I was using  baseurl as 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/api' when I converted it to 'http://localhost:3000/api' it works....thanks

Comment: yes...that's because 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address. Read the wiki entry I linked to

Comment: @ADyson just read the wiki article, clearly article mentions the use of 0.0.0.0 in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

In your node backend, add this above all the routes:

```
app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));
```

One request that is failing would have `Authorization` in the header. Including `credentials: true` will solve the issue.

Comment: @rajesh why should he? it wasn't the answer. See the comments above